# Run a python file on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

Every time I try and run my python code in the terminal I always get something like this,

```
Hello World
Enter your name: Tyler
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "HelloWorld.py", line 3, in <module>
name = input('Enter your name: ')
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Tyler' is not defined
```

I am new to Python so please forgive me, I usually program in c# but Windows broke so I am trying to learn python.

Here is my code:

```
print('Hello World')

name = input('Enter your name: ')

print('Hi', name)

age = input('Enter your age: ')

age = int(age)

if (age == 35):
    print('You are as old as Derek Banas')
if (age == 19):
    print('You are the same age as me!')
else:
    print('You are a different age than me')

print('Hello', name, 'You are', age, "It's nice to see you again!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using python 3 so to run it from terminal you need to use `python3 script.py` instead of `python script.py`

Comment: So i used this in my code and now IDLE is giving me an error. Is raw_input just something used for terminals or am I typing it wrong? By the way I like how you explained yourself!

Comment: Thank you. what error do you have ? raw_input is a python 2 function used to read strings it works only in python 2 if you have python 3 you should have no error to begin with

Comment: if you want to run python3 from terminal use python3 instead of just python

Comment: If you run it with `python3 script.py`, use `input` instead of `raw_input`.

Comment: William is right, once I used python3 instead of python it fixed it! Is there a way to change that by default?

Comment: Add the Python 3 executable location to your `PATH` variable and you can call it from the terminal using `python3`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: Then it should work. I don't see any errors in his code. Maybe he's trying to run it on Python 2.7.

Comment: If he is trying with py2, the error should be referent to the print function. Or maybe he's importing it from py3k (i.e. `from __future__ import print_function`)

Comment: Could be it. `input` should work just OK on Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for being patient with me, here is the solution I have found based on everyones input! I was coding it in IDLE using Python 3.4 then just typing python in terminal. When I changed it to raw_input it fixed it but gave me an error running it in IDLE.

Here is the solution I have found:
When I use cd Desktop/Python then running it from there I should use Python3 not python so the code will look like this:

```
cd Desktop/Python
python3 HelloWorld.py
```

That fixed my issue! Thanks everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input('Enter your name: ')
age = input('Enter your age: ')
```

instead use

```
name = raw_input('Enter your name: ')
age = raw_input('Enter your age: ')
```